# It is possible execute a single function of my program as another process? (c++, linux)

Tags: c++, linux, process

My program use fanotify for monitoring file access. Since my program accesses files too, I have to check that my program's pid is not the same that the process's accessing the file.

```
get_pid() != event_metadata->pid
```

When this condition becomes true, my program does its thing.

Now, I want write some unit tests, but the tests requires to access files in order to test. But due to above condition, the tests's pid is the same that the process accessing  files. So tests don't do anything.

It is possible run a simple function (lets say, function for accessing files) in an isolated process without make an entire copy of the parent process (like fork() does).

Here  is a general idea of I want:

```
void access_files(){...}

void do_test(){
    ...             // A great C++ spell here.
    access_files()  // Execute this and only this function in other process.
    ...             // More test stuffs here.
}
```

Solutions based on running separated scripts or programs are already checked.

Comment: Fork doesn't make an entire copy, it marks the underlying pages as copy on write. `vfork` may have semantics that are useful to you if you only care about Linux.

Comment: Why don't you opt for running access_files in a separate thread and depending on your requirement you can wait for thread to finish or do some other job?

Comment: Nik, I'm running access_files in a separated thread, but remember all threads has the same pid.

Comment: Flexo: vfork did the magic. Thanks. If you want post an answer it will be welcome.